# Flutter: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':path_provider:classpath'

Tags: java, android, flutter

My flutter project was working fine, but after I install path_provider package it gives me the following error when trying to run it:

```
>FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> * What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':path_provider:classpath'.
   > Could not find builder.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:3.3.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/3.3.0/builder-3.3.0.jar
   > Could not find bundletool.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.6.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.6.0/bundletool-0.6.0.jar
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

My development environment:

Windows 10

android studio 3.6.3

flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.9-stable

Gradle 5.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

- Go to your FlutterSDK folder, then go to `\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\`
- Then delete path_provider-x.x.x (specified version)
- Run the app.

It worked for me.